# use fabric js canvas as a threejs 3d model texture

Tags: javascript, three.js, fabricjs, gltf

juste starting to learn threejs and to do so decided to build a t-shirt configurator in combination with fabric js. my goal is that the user can upload a picture to the canvas (cnvs) which will be mapped to the gltf model of a t-shirt the probleme is that the texture doesn't show .
code :

```
var canvas2 = new fabric.Canvas('cnvs', {
backgroundColor: 'red'
});
fabric.Image.fromURL('eo.png', function(myImg) {
//i create an extra var for to change some image properties
var img1 = myImg.set({ left: 0, top: 0 ,width:150,height:150});
canvas2.add(img1); 
canvas2.renderAll();
});

var canvasTexture = new THREE.CanvasTexture(canvas2);
canvasTexture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
canvasTexture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;

const gltfLoader2 = new GLTFLoader();
gltfLoader2.load('tshirt2.gltf', (gltf2) => {
model = gltf2.scene;
model.traverse(child => {
 console.log(child.material);
if (child.material && child.material.name === 'Pattern2D_13095') {
// Pattern2D_13095
child.material.map = new TextureLoader().load(  new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
  map: canvasTexture,
  
}));
}
});
canvas2.on("after:render", function() {
model.material.map.needsUpdate = true;
});

canvas2.on('mouse:down',function(event){
if(canvas2.getActiveObject()){
 alert(event.target);
 }

})


scene.add(model);
model.rotation.x = 1.5;
model.position.y=310;
model.position.x=-300;
model.position.z=-100;
model.scale.set(1000,1000,1000);
});


});


function resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer) {
const canvas = renderer.domElement;
const width = canvas.clientWidth;
const height = canvas.clientHeight;
const needResize = canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height;
if (needResize) {
renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
}
return needResize;
}






function render() {

if (resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer)) {
const canvas = renderer.domElement;
camera.aspect = canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight;
camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
}

renderer.render(scene, camera);

requestAnimationFrame(render);
}





function animate(){
requestAnimationFrame(animate);
cloudParticles.forEach(p => {
    p.rotation.z -= 0.001;
 
   
 });


root.rotation.z -= 0.01;

renderer.render(scene, camera);  
model.material.needsUpdate = true;


}
animate();
```

lights/camera:

```
 let cloudParticles = [];
let root;
let model;
const scene = new THREE.Scene();

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 
1000 );
camera.position.z = 2;
camera.rotation.x = 1.16;
camera.rotation.y = -0.12;
camera.rotation.z = 0;
const canvas = document.querySelector('#c');
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas});
scene.fog = new THREE.FogExp2(0x11111f, 0.002);
renderer.setClearColor(scene.fog.color);
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);


document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

let directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xff8c19);
directionalLight.position.set(0,0,1);
scene.add(directionalLight);
let orangeLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xcc6600,50,450,1.7);
orangeLight.position.set(200,300,100);
scene.add(orangeLight);
let redLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xd8547e,50,450,1.7);
redLight.position.set(100,300,100);
scene.add(redLight);
let blueLight = new THREE.PointLight(0x3677ac,50,450,1.7);
blueLight.position.set(300,300,200);
scene.add(blueLight);

let directionalLight2 = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
directionalLight2.position.set(-110,-110,-120);
scene.add(directionalLight2);
```

HTML:

```
<div class="cnvscon">
<canvas id="cnvs" height="256" width="256" ></canvas></div>       
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

here is an img of the result ( the mesh is black ):
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYTv0.jpg)
[gltfviewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxoX3.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> child.material.map = new TextureLoader().load(  new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
> map: canvasTexture }));

I'm afraid this code is incorrect. It should be sufficient to assign `canvasTexture` to the respective `map` property. Meaning:

```js
child.material.map = canvasTexture;
```

Comment: thank you for your response i just replaced it and it's still  not working this is where the error is   :
     console.log(model.material); //Cannot read property 'material' of undefined
     canvas2.on("after:render", function() {
     model.material.map.needsUpdate = true; //Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
     });

Comment: When traversing through a glTF asset, you have to check if the current object actually has a material. An instance of `THREE.Group` or `THREE.Bone` does not have such a property.

Comment: i think i am doing that with this line of code :
`if (child.material && child.material.name === 'Pattern2D_13095')`
in blender the name of the collection i need to change the texture of is 'Pattern2D_13095' 
if i console log child.material i do get a list of materials

Comment: so i managed to solve this by changing the model the texture did change but the color is black and there is no light refraction from it tryed changing metalness but still no change here is the error i am getting :
`Failed to execute 'texImage2D' on 'WebGL2RenderingContext': Overload resolution failed.`